# Use case for std::forward_as__tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdmap

Cppreference gives for `std::forward_as_tuple` the following example (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

int main()
{
     std::map<int, std::string> m;

     m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
               std::forward_as_tuple(10),
               std::forward_as_tuple(20, 'a'));
     std::cout << "m[10] = " << m[10] << '\n';

     // The following is an error: it produces a
     // std::tuple<int&&, char&&> holding two dangling references.
     //
     // auto t = std::forward_as_tuple(20, 'a');
     // m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(10), t);
}
```

What is the benefit over simply writing

```
 m.emplace(std::make_pair(20,std::string(20,'a')));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It avoids making unnecessary or potentially impossible copies of objects.

First, let's consider a value type other than `std::string`.  I'll use something that can't be copied, but this also applies to things that *can* be copied but for which it's expensive to do so:

```
struct NonCopyable
{
    NonCopyable(int a, char b) {} // Dummy
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator=(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
};
```

How can we insert that into a `std::map<int, NonCopyable> m`?  Let's go through the possibilities:

```
m.insert({10, NonCopyable{10, 'a'}});
```

This [won't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7fbcdc3ed5b0e0e).  It accepts a reference to a `std::pair` and copies it, which requires copying the `NonCopyable` object, which is impossible.

```
m.emplace(10, NonCopyable{10, 'a'}});
```

This also [won't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06f99c1de68fbed1).  While it constructs the `std::pair` value in place, it still has to copy the `NonCopyable` object.

```
m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
          std::tuple{10},
          std::tuple{10, 'a'});
```

Finally, something that [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ea07715561f8780).  The `std::pair` element is constructed in-place as are its two sub-objects.

But lets consider another situation.  Consider this class:

```
struct UsesNonCopyable
{
    UsesNonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) {}
    UsesNonCopyable(const UsesNonCopyable&) = delete;
    UsesNonCopyable& operator=(const UsesNonCopyable&) = delete;
};
```

Now how can we add elements to a `std::map<int, UsesNonCopyable> m`?

The first two options above won't work for the same reason they didn't in the previous case, but suddenly neither will the third:

```
m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
          std::tuple{10},
          std::tuple{NonCopyable{10, 'a'}});
```

This [won't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/081108d11ae4370c) because the `NonCopyable` object has to be *copied* into the `std::tuple` object that's passed to `std::pair`'s constructor.

This is where `std::forward_as_tuple` comes in:

```
m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
          std::tuple{10},
          std::forward_as_tuple(NonCopyable{10, 'a'}));
```

[This works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42c15ba55ffdc9b6), because now rather than passing `m.emplace` a tuple containing a *copy* of the `NonCopyable` object, we use `std::forward_as_tuple` to construct a tuple that holds a *reference* to the `NonCopyable` object.  That reference gets forwarded on to `std::pair`'s constructor, which will in turn forward it on to `UsesNonCopyable`'s constructor.

---

Note that much of this complication is removed with C++17's addition of [`std::map::try_emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace) as long as your key type is copyable.  The following [will work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0dcd62293238eee6) just fine and is significantly simpler:

```
std::map<int, UsesNonCopyable> m;
m.try_emplace(10, NonCopyable{10, 'a'});
```

Comment: Why didn't they choose to allow for the possibility of simply forwarding the arguments to the constructor of the underlying object? As in: `m.emplace(10, 10, 'a'); // constructs a NonCopyable{10, 'a'} object internally`.

Comment: @303 That's exactly what `try_emplace` does, but it wasn't added until C++17.  `emplace` directly constructs the `std::pair` entry that he map holds while `try_emplace` abstracts away the `std::pair` and takes a key and arguments to be forwarded to construct the value in place.